# Iteración con foreach con distintos estilos

Tags: php, css

Hola buenas madrugadas es posible iterar con un foreach y mostrar con distintos estilos. Me gustaría que los dos primeros registros fuesen así:

```
@foreach ($noticias as $i => $item)
  <div class="col-6">
     <div style="position: relative;" class="margenBlog">
       <div id="overlay10"></div>
         <img class="imgBlogGrande" src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}">
           <div class="cont-blogGrande">
           <div>
             <span>{{ $item->valor }}</span>
           </div>
           <h2>{{ $item->titulo }}</h2>
           <h3><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item->fecha)) }}</h3>
           <h3><i class="far fa-user"></i> Aroa Puchades</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

Los siguientes 6 registros de este modo:

```
@foreach ($noticias as $i => $item)
      <div class="col-4">
         <div style="position: relative;" class="margenBlog">
           <div id="overlay10"></div>
             <img class="imgBlogGrande" src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}">
               <div class="cont-blogGrande">
               <div>
                 <span>{{ $item->valor }}</span>
               </div>
               <h2>{{ $item->titulo }}</h2>
               <h3><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item->fecha)) }}</h3>
               <h3><i class="far fa-user"></i> Aroa Puchades</h3>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
@endforeach
```

**Y que todo el rato se repita de este modo** 2 registros con col-6 y 6 con col-4, es posible? Es decir solo cambio el `col-6` por un `col-4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar la variable loop del foreach para no hacer tanto código así, la variable loop contiene información de la iteración lo que hago acá es preguntar si el índice es menor a 2 o sea el objeto 1 y el 2 ,ya que inicia e cero , le agregue la clase col-6 de lo contrario col-4 con eso evitas varias líneas de código

```
 @foreach ($noticias as $item)
            
<div class=" @if($loop->index < 2)col-6 @else col-4 @endif">
                 <div style="position: relative;" class="margenBlog">
                   <div id="overlay10"></div>
                     <img class="imgBlogGrande" src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}">
                       <div class="cont-blogGrande">
                       <div>
                         <span>{{ $item->valor }}</span>
                       </div>
                       <h2>{{ $item->titulo }}</h2>
                       <h3><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item->fecha)) }}</h3>
                       <h3><i class="far fa-user"></i> Aroa Puchades</h3>
                      </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
        @endforeach
```

para repetir el patrón que se repita cada 8 iteraciones debes hacer un acumulador y reiniciarlo así

```
@foreach ($noticias as $item)
@php
            $contador++;
        if ($contador === 8) {
            $contador = 0;
        }
        @endphp
<div class=" @if($contador < 3)col-6 @else col-4 @endif">
                 <div style="position: relative;" class="margenBlog">
                   <div id="overlay10"></div>
                     <img class="imgBlogGrande" src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}">
                       <div class="cont-blogGrande">
                       <div>
                         <span>{{ $item->valor }}</span>
                       </div>
                       <h2>{{ $item->titulo }}</h2>
                       <h3><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item->fecha)) }}</h3>
                       <h3><i class="far fa-user"></i> Aroa Puchades</h3>
                      </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Nicolas Aldana , pero del modo que me pones una vez ponga los 6 resgistros con `col-4` volvera a hacer los dos `col-6` eso al final es lo que no se como hacer

Comment: ahh lo que quieres es que el 1 y  2 tenga col-4 y luego col-6, 7 y 8 col-4 y col-6 algo asi?

Comment: Hola @NicolasAldana exacto, las dos primeras col-6 las seis siguientes en col-4 y luego que eso se repita en bucle, es posible?

Comment: claro que si @Miguel, te voy a colocar otro fragmento de código en la misma respuesta editada, por favor revisa

Comment: Hola @NicolasAldana , me dice que la variable `contador` no existe. Y por otro lado hay forma de hacerlo con sus estilos de cada uno? es decir dentro del col-6 hay unos estilos y en los del col-4 hay otros, aunque se repita contenido lo necesito, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si lo olvide, en el controlador define la variable contador=0  y la envias como parametro a la vista y respecto a los estilos pues puedes pasar otra clase en el if, puedes colocar las clases que necesites

Comment: Listo! funcionando @NicolasAldana muchas gracias, he editado tu código ordenandolo, y utilizando el contador que trae por defecto Laravel, también añadí otro `if` para el cambio entre imagenes grandes y pequeñas

Comment: Con gusto Miguel, tengo una duda, cual es el contador que trae laravel? No lo conozco, agradeceria si me lo compartes. Saludos

Comment: No se darte una explicación amplia, a ver si algún compañero/a se ofrece y te detalla más, pero el `foreach` de Laravel incluye ya un contador haciendo esto: `$noticias as $i => $item` ese `$i` que lo puedes llamar como quieras cuenta las pasadas por el bucle, como te decia soy novato, lo aprendi viendo pero no tengo una información más detallada de como funciona. Gracias @NicolasAldana

Comment: ahh ok no te preocupes pero te explico, el $i no es de laravel es nativo de casi todos los lenguajes, es lo que llamas recorrer el arreglo por $llave=>$valor, puedes investigar como funciona. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

intente con el siguiente código como el $i siempre comienza con 0  y va implementando

```
@foreach ($noticias as $i => $item)
        @if($i==0 || $i==1 )  
          <div class="col-6">
        @else
          <div class="col-4">
        @endif
             <div style="position: relative;" class="margenBlog">
               <div id="overlay10"></div>
                 <img class="imgBlogGrande" src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}">
                   <div class="cont-blogGrande">
                   <div>
                     <span>{{ $item->valor }}</span>
                   </div>
                   <h2>{{ $item->titulo }}</h2>
                   <h3><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item->fecha)) }}</h3>
                   <h3><i class="far fa-user"></i> Aroa Puchades</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
           </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta @marcpsalbertosaavedrasanabr . Parece que funciona, pero me gustaria entender el código, como hace para poner los dos primeros con `col-6` los 6 siguientes con `col-4` y después volver a empezar?

Comment: ah veo que después de 6 iteraciones sigue poniendo `col-4` tendria que poner `col-6` no se si me explico @marcos alberto saavedra sanabr